# Should a string constants class be static?

Tags: c#, static, constants

I am working on a new project and I have noticed some code that I am not sure is true. The names and values I am using to demonstrate the question are fake.

```
public class MyConsts //Should it be static?
{
    public const string MyConst1 = "a";
    public const string MyConst2 = "b";
    public const string MyConst3 = "c";
    public const string MyConst4 = "d";
    ....
}
```

For my logic this class (that contains only consts values) should be static, so no option to initialize it, which has no sense, am I correct?

**EDIT:** I was writing the code blind so I have confused the order of string and const - and because it wasn't the target of my question I've fixed this.

Comment: The class shouldn't exist at all. You want to use resources instead.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I've seen many cases when this exact approach is a good fit and resources would at best provide no benefits. I.e. `HtmlTags.Div = "div"` is perfectly fine as collection of constants, but if put in resources it will require extra care to avoid localization.

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn - No, he should have an `IAbstractFactory` that is inherited by `ConstantsFactory` that reads constants from resources and then injects them using IOC container.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Yes, it makes sense for it to be static. That signifies your *intention*, prevents clients from even declaring a variable of that type, etc.

You'll need to move the `const` modifier *before* the type part though:

```
public const string MyConst1 = "a";
...
```

If the values could ever change, consider using `public static readonly` fields instead of `const` though - otherwise the value will be baked into any code which refers to the constants, which means you need to rebuild any client code if the values change.

(Another option is to make the constants `internal` instead of `public`.)

Comment: Thank you. Does the change to static has any affects on memory, or performance? (because as I know static classes compiles at the start of the application and not when it is called)

Comment: @MishaZaslavsky: Nope - and your "knowledge" of the difference in static classes is untrue as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Static classes compiled when everything else is compiled, they are _initialized_ once the first time they are accessed.

Answer (score 6):

Yes the class should be `static`. But related, should those values actually be `const`?

Anything declared `const` will be compiled into any referencing assemblies, so if this is a class library, say, and you put out a new version with changes to those const values, they won't be picked up by the assemblies that reference them.

In that particular case `public static readonly string` makes sense.

However, if those are only visible within a single particular assembly (for instance a console application or WinForms app), then you should declare that class `internal` and the `const`s are fine as-is.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it should be static if the values never change. As you say, it makes no sense to allow client code to instantiate it.

Answer (score 1):

If it only contains `const`s and will not contain anything else then you would be better off making it a static class to prevent instantiating and as such clogging.

Answer (score 0):

Really, it's up to you.  Static does come in handy for purely utility classes.

Keep in mind that a static class is sealed; it cannot be inherited from.